# xslt result-document "Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI: file..."

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

Using XSLT transformation I  converted my text file and i want to  split this text file to  2 distinct files using  but i can't put more than one result  to the same output file 
Whyyyyyyyyy?????????

```
MN1111111111002111111   0434212BDK INDEPENDANCEs
MN8888888888002888888  0434342BDK INDEPENDANCEE 
MN9999999999003999999   0434212BDK INDEPENDANCEs,
```

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
    xmlns:fjs1="http://soprabanking.com/amplitude">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vText"  select="unparsed-text('file:///C:/Users/felfadil/Desktop/XsltFaty/testTextOx1.txt')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLines" select="tokenize($vText,'&#10;')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$vLines"> 
            <xsl:variable name="code" select="substring(.,13,3)"/>
            <xsl:if test="$code='002'">
                <xsl:result-document method="text" href="file:///C:/Users/Desktop/XsltFaty/Tttt2.txt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So how exactly should the two files be named and which contents should they have?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to concatenate the result documents for the two input records having the same key?

One reason XSLT doesn't allow that is that the order would be unpredictable; `xsl:for-each` is allowed to process the input items in any order or in parallel.

What you should be doing is to group the input lines using `xsl:for-each-group`, and then call `xsl:result-document` once for each group.